# Passing Parameters using a Calculated member - MDX

Tags: ssrs-2008, mdx

I am trying to build a query with parameters using a calculated member.

I have created calculated members for judicial counts which are "hard coded" and the parameter I created does not effect the totals of each group.

However, I need to have each of the total counts listed with a working parameter. If there is no value for the selected judicial type a zero count should be displayed.

Im sure there is an easy way, but im fairly new to MDX/SSRS. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the query:

```
WITH 

Member  [Measures].[Jud] as
        (
        [Dim Foreclosure Loan].[Judicial Flag].[1],
        [Dim Foreclosure Loan].[FCL Stage].&[Sale Held],
        [Measures].[Loan Count]
        )
Member  [Measures].[Non-Jud] as
        (
        [Dim Foreclosure Loan].[Judicial Flag].[0],
        [Dim Foreclosure Loan].[FCL Stage].&[Sale Held],
        [Measures].[Loan Count]
        )
Member  [Measures].[Total] as
        (
        [Dim Foreclosure Loan].[Judicial Flag],
        [Dim Foreclosure Loan].[FCL Stage].&[Sale Held],
        [Measures].[Loan Count]
        )
--------------------------------    Query Begins    --------------------------------
SELECT NON EMPTY
        {
        ([Dim Date].[Calendar].[Day].Members)
        } ON ROWS,
        NON EMPTY 
        ({
        ([Measures].[Jud]),
        ([Measures].[Non-Jud]),
        ([Measures].[Total])
        }) ON COLUMNS
        FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DimForeclosureLoanJudicialFlag, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS
        FROM [Foreclosure])
        WHERE 
        (IIF( STRTOSET(@DimForeclosureLoanJudicialFlag, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1,
        STRTOSET(@DimForeclosureLoanJudicialFlag, CONSTRAINED),
        [Dim Foreclosure Loan].[Judicial Flag].currentmember)
        )CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
```

**Update**: Need help with the iif statment provided; see comments below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking but if I were to restate it, I think this is what you're trying to do. I think you want to see Jud, Non-Jud, and Total on the columns. I think you're trying to use the parameter to select a particular judicial flag. What's not clear is whether the parameter values are limited to 1 and 2 as you show for the measures, or if there is a hierarchy there for which there are children for 1 and 2. I'm going to assume the first one because it's easiest to explain and we can go from there.

You need to set up your measures for the judicial flags 1 and 2 to consider what's in the `WHERE` clause. Right now they are hard-coded and that tells SSAS to ignore whatever is in the `WHERE` clause. You need to use it conditionally by including an `IIF` statement in the Measure definition. You should return a `NULL` value as the False condition so that SSAS can execute the query optimally and then use the format_string property to fill in a zero in place of the `NULL` (which is better than using the 0 in the False condition for performance). However, your `NON EMPTY` keyword on columns will eliminate the judicial flag that's not included in the `WHERE` clause so you need to remove that. Keep it on rows so that you display only the days that have values for either Jud or Non-Jud.

Here's an attempt at your query based on my guess of what you're trying to do:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Jud] AS 
  iif(
        [Dim Foreclosure Loan].[Judicial Flag].CurrentMember is 
            [Dim Foreclosure Loan].[Judicial Flag].[1], 
            (
              [Dim Foreclosure Loan].[Judicial Flag].[1]
             ,[Dim Foreclosure Loan].[FCL Stage].&[Sale Held]
             ,[Measures].[Loan Count]
            ),
            NULL), format_string="#;#;0;0"
  MEMBER [Measures].[Non-Jud] AS 
  iif(
        [Dim Foreclosure Loan].[Judicial Flag].CurrentMember is 
            [Dim Foreclosure Loan].[Judicial Flag].[0], 
            (
              [Dim Foreclosure Loan].[Judicial Flag].[0]
             ,[Dim Foreclosure Loan].[FCL Stage].&[Sale Held]
             ,[Measures].[Loan Count]
            ),
            NULL), format_string="#;#;0;0" 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Total] AS 
    (
      [Dim Foreclosure Loan].[Judicial Flag]
     ,[Dim Foreclosure Loan].[FCL Stage].&[Sale Held]
     ,[Measures].[Loan Count]
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Dim Date].[Calendar].[Day].MEMBERS
    } ON ROWS
 , 
    {
      [Measures].[Jud]
     ,[Measures].[Non-Jud]
     ,[Measures].[Total]
    } ON COLUMNS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    StrToSet
    (@DimForeclosureLoanJudicialFlag
     ,CONSTRAINED
    ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Foreclosure]
)
WHERE 
  IIF
  (
      StrToSet
      (@DimForeclosureLoanJudicialFlag
       ,CONSTRAINED
      ).Count
    = 1
   ,StrToSet
    (@DimForeclosureLoanJudicialFlag
     ,CONSTRAINED
    )
   ,[Dim Foreclosure Loan].[Judicial Flag].CurrentMember
  )
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMATTED_VALUE;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Stacia! Great guess on what you thought I needed. The solution worked perfectly for my needs. I really appreciate the time you took to provide such a detailed answer and explanation. All the best!!

Comment: Hello Again! The iif statement provided by @Stacia works partially for my needs. I noticed the counts do not appear in SSRS until the parameter is selected. If the order of the iif statement is reversed the count appears initially, but disappears when the parameter is selected. I would like the count to appear initially and disappear only if the parameter selected is does not match. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the default value for your parameter? It'd difficult to suggest a solution without having a more complete picture of your environment.